# angularjs-dropdown-multiselect angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a dropdown-multiselect. This directive uses Bootstrap's Dropdown with the power of AngularJS directives and binding. I new to angularjs.

```
<li id="bedsLists">
    <div ng-dropdown-multiselect=""
        options="beds"
        selected-model="selectedBeds"
        checkboxes="true"
        events="{onItemSelect: onItemSelect, onItemDeselect: onItemDeselect}"
        extra-settings="{showCheckAll: false, showUncheckAll: false, dynamicTitle: false, externalIdProp: 'Value', displayProp: 'Name', idProp: 'Value'}"
        translation-texts="{buttonDefaultText: 'Beds'}">
    </div>
</li>
```

From stateParams, required value is fetched, for example "1". How to make the first checkbox selected?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In your Controller

```
  var myApp = angular.module('exampleApp',['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);

    myApp.controller('appController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.selectedBeds = [{id: 1, label: "David"}]; // add the 1st data of your 
    $scope.beds = [
        {id: 1, label: "David"},
        {id: 2, label: "Jhon"},
        {id: 3, label: "Lisa"},
        {id: 4, label: "Nicole"},
        {id: 5, label: "Danny"}];
    }]);
```